# Javascript smart filtering array of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, reactjs, knapsack-problem

i have an array of objects that has a key , value pair like below .

```
    players=[
             {
                id : 1,
              name : "player1", 
             value : 5.6, 
          position : "Goalkeeper"
             },{
                id : 1,
              name : "player1", 
             value : 7.7, 
          position : "Defender"
             },{
                id : 1,
              name : "player2", 
             value : 6.1, 
          position : "Midfielder"
             },{
                id : 1,
              name : "player1", 
             value : 7.2, 
          position : "Forward"
             },.....n ]
```

What i want to achieve is autoselect 15 players where goalkeepers should be 2 ,  5 defenders , 5 midfielders and 3 forwards from array of 700 players so that their total value is close to or equal to 100 . Any help would be appreciated :-)

Comment: The "total value" close to 100 needs to be ellaborated a bit, i mean, there are many ways to go about an array and select random things, what precisely are we looking for here, what kind of randomness you need etc

Comment: You can use filter and slice the array. How you would like to reach total of 100 points value would be up to you. You could just look for players around 100/(2+5+5+3) or you could randomly select the first few and try to make up to the total value as you select more. How complex your algorithm gets is up to you and that's exactly what defines your program.

Comment: So *close to 100* means *best team with highest values* or is that more complicated?

Comment: @Dellirium , as jonas try to elaborate , it means best team with the highest value but it should be randomly selected meaning should be different every time .

Comment: @bobin56 that statement makes no sense. A thing can't be both "best" and "different every time"

Answer (score 1):

At first seperate the players into their positions:

```
const getPosition = (arr, pos) => arr.filter(({position}) => position === pos);
```

Then use a method to combine these arrays into an array with a specified length that trys out all combinations:

```
function combinations(arr, length) {
  function* walk(start, depth) {
    for(let i = start; i < arr.length; i++) {
      if(depth) {
        for(const combo of walk(i + 1, depth - 1)) {
           yield [...combo, arr[i]];
        }
      } else {
         yield [arr[i]];
      }
    }
  }
  return walk(0, length);
}
```

Now to get all different teams we can combine them like this:

```
 function* compose(iterator, ...iterators) {
    for(const value of iterator) {
      if(iterators.length) {
        for(const combo of compose(...iterators)) {
           yield [value, ...combo];
        }
      } else {
        yield [value];
      }
   }
}

const teams = compose(
  combinations(getPosition("Goalkeeper"), 3),
  combinations(getPosition("Defender"), 5),
  combinations(getPosition("Midfielder"), 5),
  combinations(getPosition("Forward"), 3)
);
```

Now we just have to find the best team:

```
const distance = team => Math.abs(team.reduce((score, player) => score + player.value, 0) - 100);

let best = teams.next().value;

for(const team of teams) {
  if(distance(best) > distance(team)) 
    best = team;
  if(!distance(best)) break;
}
```

Comment: Hi @jonas , Appreciate a lot your support . Your solution works partially , it list the first 4 GK , 6 DEF , 6 MID and 4 FWD in an array without considering their value or randomness . Also , if you can advise how to limit autopicking more than 3 players from one club assuming you have another key for club_id in that array....Thanks again.